# Cronjob relative path not executing the file

Tags: php, linux, cron

I have set up a cronjob to run every minute. I entered the relative path but the file is not executing. When I try to run the file manually using "php cronTest.php" everything works but the crontab not running the file.

Could anyone help?

Comment: Use the full path, not relative.

Comment: I have tried the full path but still no luck.

Comment: Can you post the crontab entry, and the php script if its simple.

Comment: Crontab Entry: * * * * * usr/bin/php full/path/to/script

Php Script: mail('email@gmail.com', 'test cron job','Testing cron job');

Comment: Yeah `usr/bin/php` is also relative. Use `/usr/bin/php`. And you can test it by just execute it on the commandline (eg. `$ /usr/bin/php /path/to/script.php`). NB: it's always better to edit and expand your question to give more info. That way it's a lot more easy for others to see all details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add in your `/etc/crontab` file:

```
* *  * * *  /usr/bin/php /path/to/cronTest.php
```

To get the php path you can use `which php` command in your console.

Answer (score 1):

Crontab entries should reference the complete path to the tools you want to execute

```
* * * * * php /full/path/to/script.php
```

Some cron systems will let you set the `PATH` variable to add your own path.  But that is more a case for adding a directory full of tools, such as `/usr/local/bin` or `/opt/vendor/bin`.

Comment: I have added this:
* * * * * usr/bin/php full/path/to/script.

but no luck

Comment: @Vurkac You need leading slashed for both of your paths.